# Extract longitude and latitude coordinates into separate columns with GeoPandas geometry

Tags: shapefile, geometry, csv, geopandas

I am currently working on an [Exploratory Data Analysis for the NYC taxi dataset](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page). Since the new datasets had location ID's instead of long and lat coordinates.

```
sf = gpd.read_file(r"shape/taxi_zones.shp")
zone = pd.read_csv(r"Datasets/taxi+_zone_lookup.csv")

# Convert geometry to long/lat 
sf['geometry'] = sf['geometry'].to_crs("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.merge(yellowtaxidf, sf, left_on='PULocationID', right_on='LocationID')).drop('PULocationID',axis=1)
```

[image: attributes showing WKT polygon]

As you can see, there is two pairs of coordinates in the geometry feature.

I am wondering if there is a way to extract each pair into a separate column for pick up long/lat and drop off long/lat so that I can perform several geospatial data visualizations.

Also is my understanding that the first pair of coordinates represent pick up and the second represents drop off coordinates correct?

Comment: `As you can see...` I don't see two pairs in the image I see a polygon.  For a pick up, drop off I would expect a point

Comment: It doesn't make sense to extract polygon coordinates as separate columns. Because a polygon may contain thousands of points. I would expect a point geometry instead of a polygon, too.

Comment: In geometry column, the pair you see is the first two points' coordinates of the polygon.

Comment: @nmtoken Thank you explaining it to me - for instance I have pickup and dropoff location ID for each row of data, is there a better way of creating new columns with the long and lat data for the respective location ID's?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Hello, thanks for explaining my wrong way of thinking. Do you mean that pickup location and dropoff location ID have condensed into a single polygon feature? i do not understand how that works..

Comment: You could take the centroid of each polygon and create lat long columns of that point. It depends on what you want to do / use the coordinates for.

Comment: @BERA i have tried however i am getting UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'centroid' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation. But I've already projected using to.crs so I'm lost.